# Any recommendations for SharePoint Online PowerShell Debugging Tools

Tags: powershell, debugging, online

I just discovered code.visualstudio.com, which even has intellisense for PowerShell scripts. Debugging those scripts, especially when the target is SharePoint Online, is a different matter.

Does anyone here have a recommendation or two for a reasonably good debugging tool for PowerShell scripts intended to work in a SharePoint Online context.

Thanks in advance
Josh

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the Powershell ISE with the SharePoint Online management shell loaded and a custom module.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Comment: Eric, does the custom module you mention provide debugging functionality or is it just related directly to the SharePoint application you're working on?

Comment: The other module is for administrative tasks, essentially wrapping business logic around the SPO commandlets to do what we need to do. I haven't seen any debugging modules, powershell and spo is pretty "easy", it either works or it doesn't.